# Using Jquery Quicksand with links instead of form values

Tags: jquery, quicksand

Here is my working code: http://www.metropoliscreative.com/jake_test/index.html

I'm trying to use the Jquery Quicksand plugin to filter two types of data. **I have this currently working with the two dropdown forms at the top.** I'm trying to instead get them to work with the links below. Since links don't have a val() like the form selections, I'm not sure how I would go about getting those links to correspond...

*Edit: I suppose the issue is less about the plugin and more about porting the use of an 's val attribute into an equivalent use on an . It seems to me that an  can't "store" a value in the same way a form can?

Thanks in advance for your time. I've been struggling for a couple days now! :D

Comment: Might I suggest rewriting this into a question about porting the use of an <option>'s val attribute into an equivalent use on an <a>, rather than focus on the specific jQuery plugin?

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the suggestion. That's a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking is pretty easy to achieve. Two options:

1. Put whatever values you're using in the "value" attribute of your  tags in the "href" attribute of your  tags.
2. Leave the "href" attribute alone and use a custom attribute (HTML5 now allows this) named as such: "data-attributename"

After your links are setup in this way, bind click events to them using jQuery and, in the function handling the click, grab the value from the attribute:

```
$('.myList a').click(function(){
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('href');

   // Filtering function using "filterValue" as input...
});
```

Substitute the usage of attr('href') above for whichever technique you're using.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Bruno,

Thanks so much for the quick response! I've updated this link:http://www.metropoliscreative.com/jake_test/index.html

I have the new var in there along with the new custom attribute, but it doesn't quite seem to work yet. I'm wondering if its because the $filterAlpha/Beta aren't connecting right?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi Bruno, I figured it out. You got me on the right track! Thanks so much! Best regards,

Jake

Answer (score 0):

You can select any element in a link just like in a form element by using jQuery("a").attr("href"); You can replace "href" with whichever attribute you'd like to select, eg. "rel"

Answer (score 0):

This a good place to try out the HTML5 data- attribute spec. It works all the way back to IE6 and you can stick any arbitrary data onto just about any element without non-semantic workarounds like stuffing data into the href.

Example:

```
<li><a data-val="1" name="bp">Brochure Packages</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks!

http://www.metropoliscreative.com/jake_test/index.html

I've updated the page with the new attribute, but it does not seem to be working quite yet. Any ideas?